# Is there a way to tell git to give me the commit which moved a line in a file?

Tags: git

I have a log that shows a stack trace.  Each line in the stack trace shows the function called, filename and line number.

Thing is, is that these don't align with the build that it's supposed to be.  So, I need to know when the function was moved from the current location to the location in the past.

E.g.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ns1.ns2.cn.fn2(t1 p1, t2 p2) in c:\path\file2.cs:line 456
at ns1.ns2.cn.fn1(t1 p1, t2 p2) in c:\path\file1.cs:line 123
...
```

In this case, in the past, `ns1.ns2.cn.fn1(t1 p1, t2 p2)` was called which called another function  `ns1.ns2.cn.fn2(t1 p1, t2 p2)` in file `c:\path\file1.cs` on line `123`.

However, currently, that line is on line `223`, which is 100 lines lower.

Is there a way to tell git to tell me when lines were added prior to 223 which moved it down 100 lines?

Comment: Maybe `git  blame` ?

Comment: Sure, if you know the content of the inserted lines you can easily ask when they appeared.

Comment: @matt, I don't know the content of the inserted/changed lines.  Git does.

Comment: So you can't actually see the code that precedes line 223?

Comment: @matt, I can see it, but it's 123 lines of code.  (actually a lot more).

Comment: Turns out that the release build was outputting the incorrect line numbers.  It moved the line number 3 lines back. GAH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I figured out was to make a script to look at all of the different versions of the file:

```sh
$  export file="path_from_repo_root/file1.cs";\
git log --pretty=short -u -L 1,99999999:"$file"|perl -e '
use warnings;
use strict;
my ($linesAdded, $linesDeleted) = (0, 0);
while (<>) {
 if (/^commit ([a-f0-9]+)/ and !eof()) {
   my $linesDiff = ($linesAdded - $linesDeleted);
   print;  # prints commit hash
   if ($linesDiff) {
     system("git show $1:$ENV{file} | grep -n --color=always fn2");
   }
   ($linesAdded, $linesDeleted) = (0, 0);
 } elsif (/^-/ ) {
   ++$linesDeleted;
 } elsif (/^\+/) {
   ++$linesAdded;
 }
}' | less -R
```

Which will spit out all of the commit hashes to the file and the location of the function in the file if the number of lines in the file have changed.

Note that this isn't a perfect solution, but it was good enough to find what I needed.  Also, 99999999 could have been changed to a the line where the function currently resides (I think), but I wasn't sure, so I just basically said to look at the entire file.

Comment: Nah. This is a one liner using the Pickaxe if you know any of the text that was introduced.

Comment: I know how to use pickaxe, but I wasn't looking for a line that was introduced.  I was looking for a line that has been moved to another location in the file.  A very important difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log -G<regex>` in the same way as "pickaxe" (`-S<regex>`) and it will show you all changes where a matching line is added, removed, or *both*, which is what you need.  (Unlike `-S`, it doesn't skip cases where the number of matches is the same before and after a commit.)

This won't narrow down to *only* moves, but it should usually be enough to find what you need.